# paint fence in Lintcode - python solution with Memory Limit Exceeded

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm solving the [paint fence](http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/paint-fence/) problem in lintcode with Python. In the python code, I defined a list with only 4 elements and run the loop to update the last three elements according to the recurrence equation, but the submission was failed and told me "Memory Limit Exceeded". Here is the code:

```
class Solution:
    # @param {int} n non-negative integer, n posts
    # @param {int} k non-negative integer, k colors
    # @return {int} an integer, the total number of ways
    def numWays(self, n, k):
        # Write your code here
        table = [0, k, k*k, 0]

        if n <= 2:
            return table[n]

        # recurrence equation
        # table[posts] = (color - 1) * (table[posts - 1] + table[posts - 2])
        for i in range(3, n + 1):
            table[3] = (k - 1) * (table[1] + table[2])
            table[1], table[2] = table[2], table[3]

        return table[3]
```

I didn't find anything wrong within this code. Can someone help me to figure it out?

Comment: if `k=1`, return 0

Comment: Thanks. I passed the test by adding this line, but I think this is not the real solution, because when I test a same number of n with k = 2, there is still 'memory limit exceeded' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xrange` instead of `range`. See [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=xrange#xrange) for more info.